# How to select datetime from ORACLE db using IST timezone

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle database is hosted in US. Application server hosted in UK.

I am trying to access the oracle application from India, how can I write a query that will show IST time. (Local machine time).

This is an oracle form, so no coding can be done.

Tried below but did not worked

```
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(current_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: i don't know about oracle forms; but you can use the TZ_OFFSET function to IST.

Answer (score 1):

First change the timezone of your session:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Calcutta';
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') FROM dual;
```

Note, you cannot use the short name, because 'IST' is also used for "Indian Standard Time" and "Iran Standard Time" and "Israel Standard Time" and "Indonesian Standard Time".

Thus Oracle requires either the full name (see [IANA time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)) or UTC Offset, e.g. `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '+5:30';`. However, this is more risky in case your country uses DST (Daylight Saving Time)

Answer (score 0):

Indian time is +5.5 hours from GMT, `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)` gives time in GMT for any Oracle server

```
select to_char(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) + 
       (5.5/24), 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse : You are correct, Indian isn't under DST and thus this query will always work for India :)

Answer (score -1):

Change your timezone with this first,

```
systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'IST'
```

Comment: It is. But probably it should be `select systimestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata' from dual;`

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry I cannot undo my downvote. Minor correction for your post: It must be `'Asia/Calcutta'`

Comment: @Wernfried - no problem :-) I should have been more explicit in the answer